# What causes a steel gurney to accelerate towards an MRI machine?

Tags: electromagnetism, medical-physics

What is the basic concept in electromagnetism that explains the MRI projectile effect in which steel objects such as gurneys crash into an MRI machine with a force that is sufficient to kill or severely injure a person?

Answer (score 0):

MRI machines are giant electromagnets. When they are on they generate strong magnetic fields by running electric currents through coils of wires. The force is magnetism.